# No puedo eliminar una columna en Excel 2016. Error de Memoria

Tags: excel, windows10, microsoft-office, out-of-memory-error

Al intentar borrar una columna de Excel, me aparece un error que dice "There isn´t enough memory to complete this action". Que esta pasando?

[image: La columna sombreada es la que quiero eliminar]

Comment: probaste reiniciando tu pc? (y no es broma)

Comment: si, reinicie jeje

Comment: ¿Cuánto pesa el archivo? ¿Tiene macros activas o que se activen cuando borras la memoria? ¿Has probado deshabilitando macros y deshabilitando cálculo antes de borrar?

Comment: Formatea la Tabla y después intenta borrarla así descartas que sea un problema de tu Excel.

Comment: Hay que apagar la actualización automática de las fórmulas. Luego la puedes prender

Answer (score 0):

Ese error es frecuente, especialmente en la utilización de diferentes formatos en tu libro. Siempre recuerda que cada formato de columna (sea color, tipo de fuente, etc) es un proceso extra para Excel más en la acción de copiar.

El Troubleshooting que te recomiendo es verificar que no tengas actualización automática de vínculos ni formatos condicionales duplicados, también verifica que no tienes celdas extras que solo te ocupan memoria, recuerda que si hay una fila en blanco, debe estar realmente vacía y el scroll no debe detectar; veo que si la detecta.

Reitero que puede ser algo con el exceso de formato de tu libro, te recomiendo "limpiar" el documento lo mayor posible ocupando estrictamente lo necesario para evitar los desbordamientos de memoria. Borra todas las filas, el scroll solo te debe mostrar lo que tienes datos.

Saludos